# How to properly subscribe to more than 1 stock market ticker using WebSocket, SwiftUI and Combine?

Tags: swift, websocket, swiftui, combine

I'm new to WebSocket and SwiftUI and am trying to subscribe to more than one ticker at the same time using Finnhub, so I can receive real-time stock market price. However, when I subscribe to one ticker manually by sendMessage method ("{"type":"subscribe","symbol":"BINANCE:BTCUSDT"}"), and try to add another ticker, let's say BINANCE:ETHUSDT for instance, it worked only by duplicating the code below, and the return of the API comes with the two tickers at the same position in the array. When I add to the row in the UI, both tickers share the same row. Here's the API documentation: https://finnhub.io/docs/api

Any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

```
private func sendMessage()
    {
        let string = "{\"type\":\"subscribe\",\"symbol\":\"BINANCE:BTCUSDT\"}"
        
        
        let message = URLSessionWebSocketTask.Message.string(string)
        webSocketTask?.send(message) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("WebSocket couldn’t send message because: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    @Published var tickerPrice = [StockMarketModel.LastPrice]()


    private func receiveMessage() {
        webSocketTask?.receive {[weak self] result in
            
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error in receiving message: \(error)")
            case .success(.string(let str)):
                
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let result = try decoder.decode(StockMarketModel.APIData.self, from: Data(str.utf8))
                    DispatchQueue.main.async{

                        self?.tickerPrice = result.data

                        
                        print(result.data[0].p)

                    }
                } catch  {
                    print("error is \(error)")
                }
                
                self?.receiveMessage()
                
            default:
                print("default")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I haven't used this type of API but to me it looks like what you get back in a response is a new trade(s) for one _or more_ of your subscriptions and this means you can't just replace your current array with the new values. Say you subscribe to A, B and C and you get an update with new prices for A and C then you still want to keep the old price for B. I would try with perhaps a dictionary with ticker code / price, [String: Double] instead

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you clarify what do you mean by creating a dictionary to solve this? If you have a tutorial would be nice.

Comment: You need too change your `tickerPrice` property to be a dictionary and store the ticker code (symbol) as key and the latest price as the value.

Comment: I managed to subscribe to more than one ticker, but the data is shown in one row when using WebSockets, no matter how many subscriptions I have. However, when I change tickerPrice to ```@Published var tickerPrice = [StockMarketModel.Stock(p: 10, s: "Test", t: 11, v: 122), StockMarketModel.Stock(p: 12, s: "TestData", t: 02, v: 122)], it shows in 2 rows. That's where I pass the data from webSocket:   ```let result = try decoder.decode(StockMarketModel.APIData.self, from: Data(str.utf8))
                    DispatchQueue.main.async{
                        self?.tickerPrice = result.data```